# Creating a variable out of a dataset for a range of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, datetime

I'm trying to create a variable out of a dataset for a range of dates. I have 70,000 lines, each of which have a date attached to them. I changed the date column called `"todays_date"` from an `obj` to `datetime` using format `"MM-DD-YY"`, but cannot figure out how to filter any of the dates now.

For example, say I want to create a variable like:

```
early_instances = (*all of the instances taking place before 03-23-23*)
```

or

```
later_instances = (*all of the instances taking place between 03-24-23 and 11-12-23*)
```

I tried filtering by column value like:

```
early_instances = data['todays_date'] <= data['todays_date']['04-20-20']
```

I seem to either be getting `keyerrors` or `out of range errors` when I do it that way and I cannot figure out why I'm getting either.

I've also tried using `pd.date_range()` but that seems to return just a list of dates, I'm trying to filter the dataframe to just include the dates I'm looking for, not necessarily pull just the dates into a list.

Is this an issue with changing to datetime format or misunderstanding the structure of datetime? Could someone suggest a better way to filter or organize by date in pandas df if not?

Apologies in advance because I see this question has been asked in various formats several times, but I've looked through several and don't understand any of the other posts in relation to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: An example of correct syntax could be: `early_instances = data[data['todays_date'] < '04-20-20']]`

Answer (score 0):

You should work like with any other values

```
mask = (data['todays_date'] < "03-23-23")

early_instances = data[mask]
```

or shorter

```
early_instances = data[ data['todays_date'] < "03-23-23" ]
```

---

```
mask = (data['todays_date'] > "03-24-23") & (data['todays_date'] < "11-12-23")

early_instances = data[mask]
```

---

But I'm not sure if it works with format `"MM-DD-YY"`.
It may need to create instance of `datatame`

```
#import datetime 

#day = datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 23)  # year, month, day

day = pd.to_datetime('03-23-23', format='%m-%d-%y')

mask = (data['todays_date'] < day)

early_instances = data[mask]
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'todays_date': ['04-20-20', '04-20-21', '03-23-23', '03-24-23', '11-12-23'],
    'other'      : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
})

df['todays_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['todays_date'], format='%m-%d-%y')

print(df)

print('\n--- example 1 ---\n')

mask = (df['todays_date'] < '03-24-23')
values = df[ mask ]
print(values)

print('\n--- example 2 ---\n')

mask = (df['todays_date'] > '03-24-21') & (df['todays_date'] < '03-24-23')
values = df[ mask ]

print(values)

print('\n--- example 3 ---\n')

#import datetime
#day = datetime.datetime.strptime('03-24-23', '%m-%d-%y')

day = pd.to_datetime('03-24-23', format='%m-%d-%y')
mask = (df['todays_date'] < day)
values = df[ mask ]
print(values)
```

Result:

```
  todays_date other
0  2020-04-20     A
1  2021-04-20     B
2  2023-03-23     C
3  2023-03-24     D
4  2023-11-12     E

--- example 1 ---

  todays_date other
0  2020-04-20     A
1  2021-04-20     B
2  2023-03-23     C

--- example 2 ---

  todays_date other
1  2021-04-20     B
2  2023-03-23     C

--- example 3 ---

  todays_date other
0  2020-04-20     A
1  2021-04-20     B
2  2023-03-23     C
```

Comment: You are correct. Only the last version will work as have to convert to datetime before comparison using a month first format. Could use such as `day = pd.to_datetime('03-2023-'23', format = '%m-%Y-%d')` to preserve the OP month first format.

Comment: @furas Thank you everyone for the help and the detailed answers. It looks like it was a simple syntax error on my end, I'm still having trouble with the exact M-D-Y formatting, even setting the format doesn't change how the date is displayed on the dataframe, but I decided to just forget about the formatting and take the small win.

Comment: The YYYYMMDD is generally favored for datestamps, because then alphabetical sorting is compatible with date sorting.

Comment: @WestinT if you want to see it on screen in different format then it may need to convert to string values in column. Or you can display with [df.to_string(... formatters=...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html). You may also use [df.style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) to generate formatted output on screen or to HTML file.